# List comprehension stop generating certain lists if sublist fails on check

Tags: erlang

I have a code, which generates all the possible variation (with the legnth of N) with repetition.

```
variation(1, L) ->
    [ [H] || H <- L ];
variation(N, L) ->
    [[H | T] || H <- L, T <- variation(N - 1, L)].
```

For **variation(3, [1,2,3,4])** it will generate:

[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,1,3],[1,1,1,4],[1,1,2,1],...]

I would like to check a condition during the generation of the lists. If a sublist fails, it should stop generating lists, that begins with the certain sublist.
For example if [1,1] sublist fails that condition (check), than it should not generate [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,2] etc (all of those that begin with [1,1]).

I don't know if its possible with 1 list comprehension.
So far, I have this code:

```
variation(1, L) ->
    [ [H] || H <- L ];
variation(N, L) ->
    [[H | T] || H <- L, T <- variation(N - 1, L), check([H|T]) ].
```

This solution will only return those lists, that doesn't fail the condition (it works, but really slow for big input).

If [1,1] fails, it will try to generate [1,1,1,2], but those will fail the check as well. I would need a solution, which doesn't try to generate lists that begin with [1,1,...] (or with a previously failing sublist).

Comment: Can you run the check only on `H`? Like this…

variation(1, L) ->
    [ [H] || H <- L ];
variation(N, L) ->
    [[H | T] || H <- L, check(H), T <- variation(N - 1, L) ].

Comment: I’ll add it as an answer, just for the code formatting :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small detail first: According to your question, `variations(3, [1,2,3]).` should generate `[[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,2], …]` but it actually generates `[[1,1,1], [1,1,2], …]`. I will assume the code was right and you meant to say that `variations(4, [1,2,3]).` should generate `[[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,2], …]`

I wrote an alternative version of your function that, using a different order on the right side of the LC, avoids generating list when their prefix is already false when checked with `check/1`:

```
variation(1, L) ->
    [ [Elem] || Elem <- L ];
variation(N, L) ->
    [ Init ++ [Last] || Init <- variation(N-1, L), check(Init), Last <- L].
```

As you can see, since `check(Init)` happens **before** `Last <- L`, `Last` is only generated if `check(Init) == true`.
That will likely have the effect you were looking for.

But… be careful. I'm using `++` in the left side of the LC. You should definitely benchmark your code and see if that has an impact on performance or not.

If it does, **and only if it does**, you might want to consider using something like this:

```
variation3(1, L) ->
    [ [Elem] || Elem <- L ];
variation3(N, L) ->
    [ lists:reverse([Last|lists:reverse(Init)]) || Init <- variation2(N-1, L), check(Init), Last <- L].
```

Maybe worth it, maybe not… you will need to benchmark your stuff to figure that out.

Comment: It won't work for me I need to check [H|T]. Unfortunately, the head check is not enough. I need to check the sublists: So if [1] sublist fails, it should not generate lists that begin with 1. I need this for performance reason.

Comment: Or another solution would be to generate variations without list comprehension. So it would generate 1 variation, and check it. After this, it would give another variation etc... But list comprehension will load every source lists, so for HUGE inputs, we will run out of memory. But I don't know how to do this without list comprehension

Comment: OK. I'll amend my answer.